# css two columns - one fixed width

Tags: html, css

I want to have two columns (content and sidebox), where sidebox will have fixed width and content will shrink as necassary.

At some point, they will both stack to 100% width, but i want to have content first. The problem with this solution is that sidebox comes first.

I don't want to use floats and percentage because i don't want to shrink the sidebox.

**html:**

```
    <aside class="sidebox"> <!-- i don't want this to come first after media query applied -->
        sidebox
    </aside>
    <section class="content">
        content
    </section>
```

**css:**

```
.content {
    margin-right:200px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
}

.sidebox{
    width:180px;
    float:right;
    height:100px;
    background-color:yellow;
}


@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .sidebox {
        float:none;
        width: auto;
     }
     .content {
         margin-right:0px;
      } 
}
```

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/72Lad2zf/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following:

```css
.container {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.content {
    display:table-cell;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
}
.sidebox {
    display:table-cell;
    width:180px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .content, .sidebox {
        width:100%;
        display:block;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <section class="content">content</section>
    <aside class="sidebox">sidebox</aside>
</div>
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/72Lad2zf/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You need change the html structure and need to use `float` in `.content` but float doesn't shrink the width.

**html**

```
<section class="content">
    content
</section>
<aside class="sidebox">
    sidebox
</aside>
```

**css**

```
.content {
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    float:left;
    width:calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

**[working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/72Lad2zf/3/)**